# Can an application load balancer route to s3 to host a static website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-application-load-balancer

Is it possible for an application load balancer to route to an s3 bucket to host a static website?  The same alb would also route to apigateway via a vpc endpoint.

Comment: Consider CloudFront for this; you can add both the S3 and the ALB as origins.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385706/using-a-s3-static-site-with-an-application-load-balancer

Comment: No it can't. Use CloudFront.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this isn't possible.

Take a look at Cloudfront instead:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/index.html

Use your S3 bucket and the ALB as origins in your setup.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible with vpc 3s *interface* endpoint.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/hosting-internal-https-static-websites-with-alb-s3-and-privatelink/

Major problem with this approach through is that interface endpoint uses s3 REST API. Which means that you couldn't specify fallback to your `index.html` in case of 404 errors. This means that if you host your SPA code and user enter in a browser `host:port/some/logical/path/within/your/app` you will get XML 403 or 404 error instead of served `index.html`.

And this problem makes this feature almost non-usable, if you have a requirement to allow bootstarp of your apps from deep links

Comment: In the "deep links" case mentioned above, we can use "hash" router in our SPA. For example, in React Router, use `HashRouter`. So the URL will end up like `host:port/index.html#some/logical/path/within/your/app`.

Comment: @Ameba since the interface endpoint here is just the way to reach out to the s3 service, not the particular bucket behind it, how should the request be properly routed to the bucket we're interested in?

Comment: @kolyaiks
on ALB rules level before forwarding a request to the target group, which contains IP addresses of the s3 interface endpoint in your subnets, you must specify s3 bucket DNS name in a Host header: bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com

Comment: @kenberkeley
yes, hash routing is an option to keep all explicitly within index.html namespace. I don't remind already whether I tried hash explicitly or not. But my tests showed that s3 REST API maps explicitly. 

In your example, if you won't have an object `app` located at the `index.html#some/logical/path/within/your/` prefix - you still will get an error. I.e. despite of the fact that it is REST api, it doesn't process requests as a web servers do. it's just 1:1 mapping to the object in s3